# Type '0 | Element | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Element'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting an error as:

`Type '0 | Element | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Element'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any>'.ts(2322)`

when I do conditional render. How to render by condition here?

```
export const Home: FC = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [initials, setInitials] = useState<InitialProps[] | null>(null);
  useEffect(() => setInitials(initialInitialPropsSchema), []);
  return initials?.length && <Header initials={initials} />;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return initials?.length && <Header initials={initials} />;
```

This is the problematic line. Since the return type should be a React element, you might want to return something digestable if your initials are not initialised. Although not the prettiest, returning empty fragment should work:

```
return initials?.length ? <Header initials={initials} /> : <></>
```

Alternatively, you can return null:

```
export const Home: FC = (): JSX.Element | null => {
  const [initials, setInitials] = useState<InitialProps[] | null>(null);
  useEffect(() => setInitials(initialInitialPropsSchema), []);
  return initials?.length ? <Header initials={initials} /> : null;
};
```

Or some loading state:

```
export const Home: FC = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [initials, setInitials] = useState<InitialProps[] | null>(null);
  useEffect(() => setInitials(initialInitialPropsSchema), []);
  return initials?.length ? <Header initials={initials} /> : <span>loading</span>;
};
```

Comment: If i do null, `Type 'Element | null' is not assignable to type 'Element'.` if I do fragment `Fragments should contain more than one child` I put empty `<div />`